# Deploying a Ruby app from GitHub on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

I'm really new to this sort of thing, and for the most part I work with JavaScript, but I found a pretty cool Ruby app that will help in what I am trying to build.

https://github.com/davidgaya/youtube_rb contains some ruby code for obtaining the stream URL, from there I intend to use EchoNest to create a short of music fingerprinting app for Youtube videos.

Anyway, here's what I wanna do, perhaps you guys might have a better solution.

```
Obtain the stream URL for a youtube video. Use that video to either stream the video or
the audio feed in the background while processing it with EchoNest's API to 
determine the artist.
```

How would I go about adding that GitHub app to my heroku ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a Ruby app - it's just a small lib. And according to the README, it is incomplete as well.

Assuming it is usable, you'd first have to decide how you'd like to create a Ruby app to use this lib in. I'd suggest [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), since it is lightweight and will allow you to easily setup a GET or POST route so you ping the app and have the URI returned. Heroku's [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby) explain [how to deploy a Sinatra app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack).

On a separate note, since you are more comfortable using JavaScript, then why set up the Ruby app at all? A quick search found me a [promising looking JavaScript library](https://github.com/endlesshack/youtube-video) for grabbing the source URI for a YouTube video.